# A Dices Probability Riddle

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, probability

Bob (A), Steven (B) and Joe (C) were playing with dices, each one of them made his own dice and wrote a number between 1-6 on each side of his dice. 
After playing for a while they've noticed that :

**(A) usually gets a higher number than (B)**

**(B) usually gets a higher number than (C)**

**And surprisingly (C) usually gets a higher number than (A)**

How is that possible?

---

**Hint**: they could've used the numbers 1-6 any number of times, example : the cube 6,6,6,6,6,6 is legit

---

I've stumbled upon this riddle at a local riddles site (they don't mind if you post their riddles else where)
Good luck!

Comment: (This is a duplicate)

Comment: Yep it does, had no idea it was already asked, thanks!

Comment: Most of the classical problems are :-) It is an interesting problem nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah I've managed to answer it myself but purely out of trying out different combinations, I find it really counter intuitive, really cool though (: